# svn revert changelist not enough arguments provided?

Tags: svn, revert, changelist

I've seen similar questions asked, but not quite the same...

I have a changelist (called "revertme") and I'd like to just be able to revert all the files in the changelist in one fell swoop. svn help revert seems to indicate I can do that with

```
svn revert --cl revertme
```

but when I try that command I get

```
svn: E205001: Not enough arguments provided
```

Any advice?

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201612.mbox/%3c20161216191302.GA23272@fujitsu.shahaf.local2%3e

Answer (score 0):

Add the directory **path**, and include the **recursive** option:

`svn revert --recursive --changelist <name of changelist> <path>`

For example, to recursively revert changes listed in changelist `readme` starting from the current directory:

```
svn revert --recursive --changelist revertme .
```

or

```
svn revert -R --cl revertme .
```